# I am having trouble understanding certain parts of this code. What is break_space_position and what are the bounds of this For Next loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to understand this code. In following the logic, I am not understanding the bounds of the For Next loop (what is next referring to? where does it end?) and what break_space_position is. Hoping you all can help.

I've already tried reading about For Next loops and googling break_space_position

```vb
Sub parse_names()
    Dim thename As String
    Dim spaces As Integer

    Do Until ActiveCell = ""
        thename = ActiveCell.Value
        spaces = 0
        For test = 1 To Len(thename)
            If Mid(thename, test, 1) = " " Then
                spaces = spaces + 1
            End If
        Next
        If spaces >= 3 Then
            break_space_position = space_position(" ", thename, spaces - 1)
        Else
            break_space_position = space_position(" ", thename, spaces)
        End If
        If spaces > 0 Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = Left(thename, break_space_position - 1)
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = Mid(thename, break_space_position + 1)
        Else
            ' this is for when the full name is just a single name with no spaces
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = thename
        End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
End Sub

Function space_position(what_to_look_for As String, what_to_look_in As String, space_count As Integer) As Integer
    Dim loop_counter As Integer
    space_position = 0
    For loop_counter = 1 To space_count
        space_position = InStr(loop_counter + space_position, what_to_look_in, what_to_look_for)
        If space_position = 0 Then Exit For
    Next
End Function
```

if the original cell contains "Dr. William Healer" then after running this code there would be a cell containing "Dr. William" and a cell containing "Healer." My ultimate goal once I understand this block of code is to edit it to make the result "William" "Healer"

Comment: Which `For...Next`? There are two. Also proper [indentation](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) would make this easier to follow. `break_space_position` is a variable.

Comment: @BigBen Sorry, that was the way the code was indented when I found it. I just approved an edit to fix that though. Really I'd like to know for both of them.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Split a space-delimited name into different cells? Or discard the title `Dr`? This code could use a rewrite, we may be able to propose something better.

Comment: the names I have to parse out will often be something like "Dr. William Healer" or "Bob Smith MBA" and I want to write code that will always give me the first name in one cell and the last name on the adjacent cell (in the same row). I was hoping if I could understand what the "break_spaces_position" is then maybe I could make some edits to get this code to do what I am attempting

Answer (score 1):

You can insert other tokens in addition to `Dr.` or `Mrs.`. Just divide them by `|` pipe character.

```
Function GetFirstName$(cell$)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "(Dr.|Mrs.)*\s*(\w+)"
        With .Execute(cell)
            If .Count > 0 Then
                GetFirstName = .Item(0).SubMatches(1)
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Function

Sub TestGFN()
    MsgBox GetFirstName("Dr. William Healer") '// => WIlliam
    MsgBox GetFirstName("Bob Smith MBA")      '// => Bob
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I realy liked @JohnyL approach with regular expression, so I wanted to expand on this a bit:

```
Option Explicit

Public Type FullName
    First As String
    Last As String
End Type

Public Enum NameToChoose
    FirstName = 0
    LastName = 1
End Enum

Public Function GetName(Value As String, ChosenName As NameToChoose) As String

    Dim fn As FullName

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "^((Dr.|OtherPrefix)\s)?(\w+)\s(\w+)(\s(MBA|OtherPostFix))?$"
        With .Execute(Value)
            If .Count > 0 Then
                fn.First = .Item(0).SubMatches(2)
                fn.Last = .Item(0).SubMatches(3)
            End If
        End With
    End With

    Select Case ChosenName

        Case NameToChoose.FirstName
            GetName = fn.First

        Case NameToChoose.LastName
            GetName = fn.Last

    End Select

End Function

Sub TestFunction()

    Debug.Print GetName("Dr. William Healer", FirstName) ' "William"
    Debug.Print GetName("Dr. William Healer", LastName) ' "Healer"
    Debug.Print GetName("Bob Smith MBA", FirstName) ' "Bob"
    Debug.Print GetName("Bob Smith MBA", LastName) ' "Smith"

End Sub
```